# Worse performance of Z3 on CNF benchmarks

Tags: z3

I am working on an approach which basis on the CNF (i.e., NNF + SNF + PNF +
AND-pull-out/Tseitin) of the input problem -- an FOL formula.

I observed that (for all most benchmarks) the performance of Z3 on CNF formulas
is much more worser compared with its the performance on the original formulas. Here 
is an example for this behavior:

(Good) F1: http://i12www.ira.uka.de/~elghazi/z3_cnf_vs_snf/F1.smt2

(Good) NNf+SNF(F1): http://i12www.ira.uka.de/~elghazi/z3_cnf_vs_snf/nnf+snf_F1.smt2

(Bad)  CNF(F1): http://i12www.ira.uka.de/~elghazi/z3_cnf_vs_snf/cnf_F1.smt2

My questions are:
(1) Why this is the case?
(2) Is there an optimal configuration of Z3 to handle CNF/NNF+SNF formulas?

PS:
+ I use naming (Tseitin) during the CNF generation only if needed.
+ I use the textual interface to call Z3.

Aboubakr Achraf El Ghazi

Comment: You could write the CNF in DIMACS format rather than in SMT2 and use Z3 with the /dimacs flag. My experience is that Z3 /dimacs is much faster than most other SAT solvers.

Comment: My formulas (see examples) are, in general, not propositional.